have email template which include detail link of my object.when i am getting email its not coming as hyperlink.instead its getting as plain text
classic email template -
    <p>Hi {!Receiving_User.Name},</p>
    
    <p>You have been tagged in a chat for claim - {!WOD_2__Claim__c.Name}.</p>
    
    <p><a href="{!WOD_2__Claim__c.Link}">Click here</a>to go to claim detail page.</p>
    
    <p>Regards,<br>{!User.Name}<p>

Apex code -

public static void setEmailTemplate(String emailTempBody, String emailSubject, String recordId, List<User> userList) {

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMessageList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    String sobjectName = '';

    String userObjectFields = '';

    List<String> lstrecipientFields = new List<String>();

    Configuration_Setting__mdt fetchAvailableStatus = TWoDMetadataUtility.getConfigurationSettingMetaData('Custom_Mail_Config');

    

    if (fetchAvailableStatus != null && fetchAvailableStatus.WOD_2__isActive__c && !String.IsBlank(fetchAvailableStatus.Configuration_Value__c)) {

        Map<String, Object> configMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(fetchAvailableStatus.Configuration_Value__c);

        sobjectName = (String) configMap.get('SobjectName');

        userObjectFields = (String) configMap.get('FieldsApiName');

        lstrecipientFields = ((String) configMap.get('recipientFields')).split(',');

    }

    List<String> fieldsList = userObjectFields.split(',');

    String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fieldsList, ',') + ' FROM ' + sobjectName + ' WHERE Id = \'' + recordId + '\'';

    SObject claimObject = Database.query(query);

    if (claimObject != null) {

        for (User u : userList) {

            for (String fieldName : fieldsList) {

                if (emailTempBody.contains(sobjectName + '.' + fieldName)) {

                    emailTempBody = emailTempBody.replaceAll(sobjectName + '.' + fieldName, String.valueOf(claimObject.get(fieldName)));

                }

                if (emailSubject.contains(sobjectName + '.' + fieldName)) {

                    emailSubject = emailSubject.replaceAll(sobjectName + '.' + fieldName, String.valueOf(claimObject.get(fieldName)));

                }

            }

            for (String recipientField : lstrecipientFields) {

                if (emailTempBody.contains('Receiving_User.' + recipientField)) {

                    String fieldValue = String.valueOf(u.get(recipientField));

                    emailTempBody = emailTempBody.replaceAll('Receiving_User.' + recipientField, fieldValue);

                }

            }

            emailTempBody = emailTempBody.replaceAll('User.Name', UserInfo.getFirstName() + ' ' + UserInfo.getLastName());

            emailTempBody = emailTempBody.replace('{!', '').replace('}', '');

            emailSubject = emailSubject.replace('{!', '').replace('}', '');

            System.debug('emailTempBody----->'+emailTempBody);

            System.debug('emailSubject----->'+emailSubject);

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{u.Id});

            mail.setSubject(emailSubject);

            mail.setPlainTextBody(emailTempBody);

            emailMessageList.add(mail);

        }

        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(emailMessageList);

        for (Messaging.SendEmailResult result : results) {

            if (result.success) {

                System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');

            } else {

                System.debug('The email failed to send: ' + result.errors[0].message);

            }

        }

    }

}

Can someone please help out?

The issue is due to the use of setPlainTextBody in your Apex code, which sends the email as plain text, causing the hyperlink to appear as plain text instead of a clickable link. To ensure the hyperlink is clickable, use setHtmlBody instead.
Update you code as:
...
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{u.Id});
mail.setSubject(emailSubject);
mail.setHtmlBody(emailTempBody); // Use setHtmlBody instead of setPlainTextBody

emailMessageList.add(mail);
...


Hi tushar.i already tried using sethtmlBody() but still its not working getting the plain text as click here
